# terminate gazebo process in a c++ or python program

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

HI,
Does anyone know how to terminate gazebo process in a program? Is there a function like gazebo::destroy() or something like that to kill all gazebo process instead of pressing ctrl+c in the terminal that gazebo is started?

Thanks
Cherry

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2604/terminate-gazebo-process-in-a-c++-or-python-program/) by [Cherry](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/262/cherry/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

From a terminal, you can use `killall gazebo` or `killall gzserver`. If you want to use python, you could adapt the code from the following:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214773/kill-process-with-python

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0